# Decimal group seperator for the fractional part

Tags: c#, number-formatting, decimal-point

I wonder what would be the best way to format numbers so that the `NumberGroupSeparator` would work not only on the integer part to the left of the comma, but also on the fractional part, on the right of the comma.

```
Math.PI.ToString("###,###,##0.0##,###,###,###")  // As documented ..
                                                // ..this doesn't work
3.14159265358979                                // result
3.141,592,653,589,79                            // desired result
```

As documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `NumberGroupSeparator` works only to the left of the comma. I wonder why??

Comment: because it is invalid. they would not be grouping the same way (thousands, tens of thous, hundreds of thous) unless the first group was 2 items: `3.14,159,265,358,979`

Comment: Huh? Obviously one needs to group starting from the comma and tenths, hundredth and thousandth would make a perfectly normal group! Which is not what it is about - it is about readability!

Comment: @TaW A bit subjective, but it's not readable for me. Number group commas suggest that it's a big number (hundreds of billions or something), until you spot the dot, which looks really odd. This is not a format that is commonly used, and that is probably the reason why it doesn't work. Before your question, I wouldn't guess that someone would want to format their numbers like that.

Comment: Well, usually one doesn't work with small decimal fractions; but when you do, you want them readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not my strong side, but I guess this may be my best bet:

```
 string input = Math.PI.ToString();
 string decSeparator = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
                      .CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
 Regex RX = new Regex(@"([0-9]{3})");
 string result  = RX.Replace(input , @"$1" + decSeparator);
```

Thanks for listening..

Answer (score 0):

A little clunky, and it won't work for scientific numbers but here is a try:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var π=Math.PI*10000;

        Debug.WriteLine(Display(π));
        // 31,415.926,535,897,931,899
    }

    static string Display(double x)
    {
        int s=Math.Sign(x);
        x=Math.Abs(x);
        StringBuilder text=new StringBuilder();
        var y=Math.Truncate(x);
        text.Append((s*y).ToString("#,#"));
        x-=y;
        if (x>0)
        {
            // 15 decimal places is max reasonable precision
            y=Math.Truncate(x*Math.Pow(10, 15));
            text.Append(".");
            text.Append(y.ToString("#,#").TrimEnd('0'));
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to work with the string generated by your `.ToString()`:

```
class Program
{
    static string InsertSeparators(string s)
    {
        string decSeparator = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

        int separatorPos = s.IndexOf(decSeparator);
        if (separatorPos >= 0)
        {
            string decPart = s.Substring(separatorPos + decSeparator.Length);
            // split the string into parts of 3 or less characters
            List<String> parts = new List<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < decPart.Length; i += 3)
            {
                string part = "";
                for (int j = 0; (j < 3) && (i + j < decPart.Length); j++)
                {
                    part += decPart[i + j];
                }
                parts.Add(part);
            }
            string groupSeparator = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator;
            s = s.Substring(0, separatorPos) + decSeparator + String.Join(groupSeparator, parts);
        }

        return s;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int n = 0; n < 15; n++)
        {
            string s = Math.PI.ToString("0." + new string('#', n));
            Console.WriteLine(InsertSeparators(s));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
3
3.1
3.14
3.142
3.141,6
3.141,59
3.141,593
3.141,592,7
3.141,592,65
3.141,592,654
3.141,592,653,6
3.141,592,653,59
3.141,592,653,59
3.141,592,653,589,8
3.141,592,653,589,79
```